# How do I limit the workspaces borders?

Tags: workspaces

Ubuntu 12.04 allows to move a window from a workspace to another using the mouse, but once in a while, that feature is very inconvenient because when the active window detaches from the top bar, it slips to the upper border and the top part of the window goes to the bottom workspace, which makes me change workspace in order grab it to the current workspace.

So basically I just need, under certain circumstances, to treat every workspace independently, with locked borders, instead of having a giant workspace divided into four sections.

Is there any way to accomplish this??

Comment: A year and no answer... Probably it is not possible. I'm looking for this too. Perhaps we should file a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 (still cannot stand Unity) but I think this will still work . . .

Are you aware that you can move the active window from one workspace to another by holding:

Ctrl + Alt + Shift + {cursor key for direction of desired workspace}

For instance, if you're in the left workspace and you want to move the current active window into the workspace on the right you just hold Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Right.

And you can jump your view from one workspace to another by holding

Ctrl + Alt + {cursor key for direction of desired workspace}

Comment: Actually, reading your question twice more, I'm not sure I've actually been of any help.

Comment: Yes, I use the keyboard directions frequently, the problem is not about changing the workspaces, but to prevent that an application that I am using on one workspace slips to another by accident, which is problematic because the options remaining on the top bar are not about the workspace but instead are related to the app in question. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to switch to the other workspace to recover your window. Because you don't need the title bar to drag a window in Ubuntu. With the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed, you can click anywhere on the window to drag it.